# ClassCastException when using custom map supplier in grouping-by

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

While I was doing a little programming exercise i stumbled upon a `ClassCastException`. As background i'm giving a simplified version of the exercise to demonstrate the problem:

> Given a string which contains only the characters `A` or `B` compute a map with the characters as keys and the number of occurrences as values. Additionally the map should always contain both characters as key (with value zero if a character is missing in the input string).

Examples:

- `"A" => {A=1, B=0}`
- `"AAB" => {A=2, B=1}`

My first solution was the following:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

public Map<Character, Long> createResult(String input) {
    Map<Character, Long> map = input.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .collect(groupingBy(c -> c, counting()));

    map.putIfAbsent('A', 0L);
    map.putIfAbsent('B', 0L);
    return map;
}
```

This solution worked but i wanted to try if it was possible to supply a map with default values to the `groupingBy` function:

```
public HashMap<Character, Long> createResult2(String input) {
    return input.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .collect(groupingBy(c -> c, this::mapFactory, counting()));
}

private HashMap<Character, Long> mapFactory() {
    HashMap<Character, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('A', 0L);
    map.put('B', 0L);
    return map;
}
```

When calling `createResult2` with input `A` a `ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$45(Collectors.java:909)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)
    at java.lang.CharSequence$1CharIterator.forEachRemaining(CharSequence.java:149)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IntIteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1908)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Streams look like overkill for this simple problem. Even worse, the stacktrace contains nothing about where *your* code caused an error. That would be reason enough for me to use a simple loop.

Comment: The last line in the stacktrace corresponds to the `collect` call in my code snippet.

Comment: @LutzHorn This question is more about why this is happening and less about how to solve the exercise.

Comment: Well, it is happening because nobody really understands streams and stacktraces thrown when streams are involved are not helpful at all :)

Comment: The map supplier should never provide a non-empty map. Besides, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37434351/2711488) may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Note when using `input.chars().partitioningBy(c -> c=='A', counting())`, you’ll get a `Map` in which both keys are always present, mapping to zero if no matching characters were found, but the keys will be `Boolean.TRUE` for `'a'` and `Boolean.FALSE` for `'b'` (actually “not `'a'`”)…

Comment: @Holger Good point, the original exercise included more than two characters though. The link you provided is very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

There is type inference magic involved, but if you want solution here it is:

Replace

```
map.put('A', 0L);
map.put('B', 0L);
```

by

```
map.put('A', new Object[]{0L});
map.put('B', new Object[]{0L});
```

But **I strongly discourage you of using this solution in practice**. Implementation details can be changed in any update and this hack stop works.

Here more explanation about "why" from `groupingBy` javadoc

> mapFactory - a function which, when called, produces a new empty Map of the desired type

`mapFactory` is second parameter. Word "empty" is very important. Implementation use created map to store arrays of `long` while iterating and then convert them to `long`. It works because of massive amount of casting inside.

Comment: Don’t do that thing with `new Object[]{0L}`. It will break as soon as you do either, use an alternative JRE or update to Java 9. In Java 9, it will use a `long[]` instead, avoiding the boxing overhead while counting, but other implementations may use even other temporary container types…

Comment: @Holger can't agree more. It is bad idea to use my solution in practice.

Comment: It was purely played joke. Also there are lot of explicit castings. From runtime perspective there is no difference, but from quality of code is bad design. I saw your link and agree that it explains situation better then my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple loop?

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> count(String input) {
    Map<Character, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put('A', 0);
    result.put('B', 0);
    for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
        result.put(c, result.get(c) + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is slower. Take two access to map per character (`get` + `put`)

Comment: @talex: just replace `result.put(c, result.get(c) + 1);` by `result.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);` and the problem is solved. It would be even more efficient when not pre-initializing the map with zeros, but do a `map.putIfAbsent('A', 0L); map.putIfAbsent('B', 0L);` afterwards, just like in the question.