# Collecting/Counting into non-empty Map throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My goal is to store the count of each item of a List inside a Map. This can be achieved by the `groupingBy()` and `counting()` methods.

The next constraint I have, is that for a value not in the List I would still need a mapping for that key to be 0. Thus all possible values must be defined.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
Map<String, Long> EMPTY = Map.of("a", 0L,
                                 "b", 0L,
                                 "c", 0L,
                                 "d", 0L);

List<String> list = List.of("a", "a", "d", "c", "d", "c", "a", "d");

Map<String, Long> count = list.stream()
                              .collect(groupingBy(s -> s,
                                                  () -> new HashMap<>(EMPTY),
                                                  counting()));
```

This code throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class [J (java.lang.Long and [J are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$53(Collectors.java:1129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
```

But if I just replace `new HashMap<>(EMPTY)` with `new HashMap<>()` the code works fine.

Am I violating something by not using an empty Map for the collect process? How would I otherwise achieve my goal using streams?

Comment: Your `mapFactory` is expected to produce an **empty** map. `() -> new HashMap<>(EMPTY)` is where the trouble is. Just use `() -> new HashMap<>()` (or `HashMap::new`)

Comment: @ernest_k where is that precised ? :)

Comment: The javadocs of `java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K>, Supplier<M>, Collector<? super T, A, D>)` state: **`mapFactory`**:  a supplier providing a new empty Map into which the results will be inserted. The stack trace leads to implementation details. Making the supplier produce an empty map resolves the problem. @azro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a weird error. Specifically, the collector that you're using (by virtue of using `Collectors.counting`) is actually accumulating into single element arrays of primitive `long`s.

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Long> summingLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> mapper) 
{
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
        () -> new long[1],
        (a, t) -> { a[0] += mapper.applyAsLong(t); },
        (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; return a; },
        a -> a[0], CH_NOID);
}
```

When `groupingBy` does a `computeIfAbsent`, it's expecting to get a `long[]` but because you already have a key for "a", you get back a `Long` which doesn't match the type that's accepted by the accumulator. That's what throws the exception.

```
A container = m.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> downstreamSupplier.get());
downstreamAccumulator.accept(container, t);
```

Later on, they [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) all of the map values:

```
intermediate.replaceAll((k, v) -> downstreamFinisher.apply(v));
```

using the 'finisher' defined above (`a -> a[0]`) to go from `long[]`s to `Long`s.

---

Yes, it's a little bit naughty but you've violated the contract

> mapFactory: a supplier providing a new **empty Map** into which the
>   results will be inserted

so it's also sort of fair enough. They're taking a `HashMap` which at compile-time was decided to be `Map<String, Long>` and they're putting `long[]`s into it. That's possible because [generics are not reified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879855/what-are-reified-generics-how-do-they-solve-type-erasure-problems-and-why-cant). At runtime, it's simply a `HashMap` capable of storing any types of keys and values.

Comment: where did you get the part about *They're taking a HashMap which at compile-time was decided to be Map<String, Long> and they're putting long[]s into it*? There are some type arguments there, like `K` and `A`, but these are inferred to `String` and `long[]`, not entirely sure what you are referring to

Comment: @Eugene the type of the map factory is `M extends Map<K,D>>`. it's inferred to be `Map<String, Long>`. If you try to explicitly specify `long[]` to `groupingBy` then it won't compile

Comment: what will not compile? well anyway, the actual code that gathers elements is `BiConsumer<Map<K, A>, T> accumulator = (m, t) -> {...}` where `A` is inferred to `long[]`; there is a `finisher` that will map into the correct `Map` type

Comment: @Eugene I don't think I can explain it any better in words. [Here is an example](https://ideone.com/Zk3vez). If you uncomment the third one then it won't compile.

Comment: @Eugene this has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37434351/2711488); the downstream collector’s intermediate container type is actually incompatible with the resulting `Map`’s value type when the finisher function is not the identity function. But a type safe alternative would need to copy the entire map during finishing and would also need a second map supplier.

Answer (score 2):

As the doc states for [`Collectors.groupingBy​(classifier, mapFactory, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector))

> Parameters:
>
> - classifier - a classifier function mapping input elements to keys
> - downstream - a Collector implementing the downstream reduction
> - mapFactory - a supplier providing a **new empty Map** into which the results will be inserted*

Answer (score 1):

Stream the list and use `groupingBy` and `counting` to convert it into `Map<String,Long>` and then use `foreach` update values in `EMPTY` map

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((k,v)->empty.put(k, v));   //java coding standards variable name should be in lower case
```

Comment: The EMPTY map should be a static final field and thus not mutated. Though I could use the foreach in this way: `Set<String> MAPPINGS = Set.of("a", "b", "c", "d");
List<String> list = List.of("a", "a", "d", "c", "d", "c", "a", "d");
Map<String, Long> count = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(s -> s, counting()));
MAPPINGS.forEach(s -> count.putIfAbsent(s, 0L));`

Comment: That should be fine, it depends on how you want it @jippiee